# Wordpress Permalinks does not work

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have migrated WordPress website to new server (Ubuntu) which is working fine.

But Permalinks settings are not working. All other pages returning me 404 error.

I already enabled `mod_rewrite`

When I use custom structure and  type **/%postname%**  it shows **Permalink structure updated.**  and while visiting the page it returns be 404  error.

I am using **/var/www/html/wordpress Installation directory/** as a folder and I have change **/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-defaul-config** to

**DocumentRoot /var/www/html/wordpress Installation directory**

and below in my .htaccess file

```
# BEGIN WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: Check permission for wordpress folder `sudo chown www-data:www-data -R wordpress` and `sudo chmod -R 777 wordpress`

Comment: i have given the above permissions. still not working

Comment: delete a `.htaccess` file once and then go to permalink and submit once again

Comment: i did  it again. still not worked for me. it created a .htacess file again with same code as above

Comment: Ok but dont create htaccess yourself, the htaccess is created when permalink is submitted. try once

Comment: yes . i didn't create  myself. i jst deleted and it will recreate when i re-submit permalinks again. still 404

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76227/discussion-between-tamil-selvan-and-hitu-bansal).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks#Fixing_Other_Issues

**AllowOverride Not Enabled** 
    Your server may not have the AllowOverride directive enabled. If the AllowOverride directive is set to None in your Apache httpd.config file, then .htaccess files are completely ignored. In this case, the server will not even attempt to read .htaccess files in the filesystem. When this directive is set to All, then any directive which has the .htaccess Context is allowed in .htaccess files. Example of enabled AllowOverride directive in httpd.config:

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
 </Directory>
```

You may also have to enable the AllowOverride directive in your DocumentRoot:

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
    # ... other directives...
    AllowOverride All
 </Directory>

You may also have to change the AllowOverride settings for the site. This is surely the case when using Mac OS X Server, but might be likewise with other systems. Usually you can find the site configuration files in /etc/httpd/sites/ 

If you don't want to set AllowOverride to all (as it is above) then your AllowOverride list must include the FileInfo directive. You must restart your Apache server for any httpd.config file changes to take effect. For more information on which overrides are allowed, read about Apache Core Features.
```

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress permalink fix

> 1.open phpmyadmin.
>
> 2.find your wordpress database.
>
> 3.Look for wp_options table.
>
> 4.Check first two fields and update option_value with your correct wordpress location.
>
> 5.Reload permalink.

Answer (score 0):

For people like me who had problems with permalinks with mod-rewrite enabled, `AllowOverride All` in the vhost and all good instuctions in the .htaccess.

I spent hours to find out that i put `AllowOverride All` in the vhost for the http ( :80 ) but not in the vhost for the https ( :443 ).

Hope this will save some time to you. =)

Answer (score 0):

WordPress permalink fix

1. open *phpMyAdmin*.
2. find your WordPress database.
3. Look for `wp_options` table.
4. Find `permalink_structure` set value to **blank**
5. Suppress/comment `modrewrite` lines in your `.htaccess` if necessary
   Your WordPress is in plain permalink mode

In case `modrewrite` is not active and interactive setup doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

All the answers forgets to mention that if you are under SSL and your httpd.conf say this:

```
`Include conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf`
```

then into httpd-ssl.conf file

you have to change

```
`AllowOverride None`
```

into
`AllowOverride All`

too!

Cheers

Comment: The order of displayed answers here at StackOverflow is unpredictable, because individually configurable. "All folks above" is therefore a meaningless reference to a set of answers or people. If you want to criticise a list of answers (which you probably should not do by the way....) you should use the links provided by the "Share" button beneath each of them. If you had taken the [tour] you might have encountered that oddity. It is part of the understanding that there are no threads on StackOverflow, there are only questions with answers.

Comment: I am sorry you have reason. Eng is not my language and  i misunderstood your meaning on reply. Also, my intent was not to be offensive. I am sorry going to edit

Comment: Thanks for editing, but now you seem to miss that other answers can still be added, which might be perfect. Consider not mentioning other answers and just contributing your own insight.

Comment: removed the comment also, sorry for the delay

Comment: You still risk that there are new answers which are perfect and give the impression that you misunderstand them. Imagine a new answer being added now. What do you know about whether it does forget or not. Also, still, do not criticise other answers, just make your contribution obvious on itself. Do not mention other answers at all. Better explain why what you propose as a solution helps and how it works. Such an explanation is a better way to be perceived as helpful.